# MYSQLI custom input query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using [mysqli class](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/PHP-MySQL-Database-Class) at one of my project, i want yours help with following...

1. How to insert custom insert query
   like we do in mysql

   > INSERT INTO payment_slip VALUES(NULL, md5(code), 'ABC', 'tester', NOW());
2. How to get last insert id using this class.

Providing methods would be great help, thanks.

Comment: If you have found an answer satisfying please accept it. Or if not, please give some additional information what you need besides that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the plain old mysql functions [mysqli has a field](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) for this too:

```
mysqli->insert_id
```

From php docs (note that this only demonstrates getting the ID, the parameters are hardcoded into the query):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO payment_slip VALUES(NULL, md5(code), 'ABC', 'tester', NOW())";
$mysqli->query($query);
printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```

Comment: can you provide me this as method, that would be a great help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Running `mysqli_insert_id()` will also work, but you should use it like **vbence** said.